# Retrieve a String property from a class instance

Tags: java, class, object

I have class A and B. 
"A" makes an instance of "B" and call a method that modify a String property. However, after the calling the property checked in "A" is null.
Can anyone help me?

---

```
Class B

private String Retro;
....
public boolean Login(final String user, final String pass){

        stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url + strLogin,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        Retro = "Done";
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                **Retro = error.getMessage();**
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error de acceso: "+Retro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //error.getMessage()
            }

        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
                parameters.put("identifier", user);
                parameters.put("password", pass);
                return parameters;
            }
        };

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        return Retro == "Done";
    }

Class A

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        accessDB = new StrapiDBAccess(this);

        signIn();
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            ...
            if (acct != null) {
                ....
                boolean result = accessDB.Login(parcelAccess.personEmail, "*******");

                tvAuth.setText(tvAuth.getText()+" "+**accessDB.getRetro()**); //
            }

        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            parcelAccess.signedIn = false;
            parcelAccess.personName = "Anónimo";
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error de autenticación con Google. Chequee que tiene internet e inténtelo de nuevo.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: paste your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please add a Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE) of your code to your post. It doesn't matter if the code soesn't work as you expect it, it will give other SO contributors a starting point from which to help _ Please visit SO Help Center & the FAQ which deals with creating MRE >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my doubt. It is impossible to do by a field, or getter or any direct way. It is neccesary to implement an interface for success or error. It would be this way:

Class B

```
public void Login(final String user, final String pass, final VolleyCallback callback){

    Retro = "";
    stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url + strLogin,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    ***callback.onSuccess("Done");***
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Retro = Retro + String.copyValueOf(error.getMessage().toCharArray());
            ***callback.onError(Retro);***
              //error.getMessage()
        }

    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("identifier", user);
            parameters.put("password", pass);
            return parameters;
        }
    };

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Error de acceso: "+ErrorCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Class A

```
accessDB.Login(parcelAccess.personEmail, "************", new StrapiDBAccess.VolleyCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String error)
                        //no pudo ingresar
                    }
                }
            });
```

Well, I hope to help anyone who has this kind of trouble